# Exporting data from a table in spanner to GCS cloud storage

Tags: google-cloud-storage, airflow, google-cloud-spanner

I need to export data out from a table/ retrieve data from one table in google spanner and load it into my on-prem hdfs/relation store. How can I do it, I cannot find anything for export here https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/spanner/cloud-client

Answer (score 2):

Spanner export is supported via Cloud Dataflow. See https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/export

The default export template all the tables of the database. It sounds like you only want data from a single table? If so, you will need to build a custom template.

You have to modify https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/spanner/ExportPipeline.java

Comment: I looked at the spanner python client api and it seems that I can just persist the result set from a sql query locally using        https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/spanner/cloud-client/snippets.py#L128